# Android Floating Notice (View) NOT popup

Tags: android, canvas, layout, view, android-custom-view

[image]

I am trying to implement a custom view like this (TextView with close button) in Android.

This view can be attached shown any place on the screen. I am trying to use Canvas but not sure how I can use it like wrap content. I tried to override `onMesaure` method and I can see that the canvas is smaller now but not able to bring down that canvas.

Questions:

1. How I can make sure canvas is not bigger than it's content and same time I can make it **visible around any existing view on the screen**.
2. Or is there anything else I should use?

NOTE 1: This should not be the popup

NOTE 2 : This can not be the toast as it should stay until use close this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Toasts` to show timed message just like the `alert()` in javascript.

here is the reference page for the same https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#kotlin

Comment: Please refer NOTE 2 I added later

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/8116 this might come to your help

Comment: as I said it should not be the popup or something like that. The whole canvas should not occupy the full screen.